# ethereumjs-wallet generate is not a function error

Tags: node.js, ethereum

What could be the reason for the following error:

> TypeError: wallet.generate is not a function

My code is as follows:

```
const wallet = require('ethereumjs-wallet');
var addressData = wallet.generate();
console.log("address: " + addressData.getAddressString());
console.log("privateKey: " + addressData.getPrivateKeyString());
```

I am using nodejs 15.12.0 and ethereumjs-wallet 7.6.3 in Windows 10

Comment: It seems you have an incorrect package. The latest version of `ethereumjs-wallet` (by `ethereumjs`) is `1.0.1` - https://www.npmjs.com/package/ethereumjs-wallet

Comment: I checked the ethereumjs-wallet module version again and it's 1.0.1. That 7.6.3 was npm version so... :) In node_modules\ethereumjs-wallet\dist\index.js file has the Wallet.generate() static method (line 165) so it should work...

Answer (score 4):

The problem was in 2. line. To get it work it has to be as follows

```
var addressData = wallet['default'].generate();
```